# RichEditBox text wrapping UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, richeditbox

I am trying to get a `RichEditBox` to take over the entire width of the app window and to be responsive to window resizing, so far the code I have is the following:

```
<RichEditBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
             Height="250"
             Name="Intro"/>
```

What I am getting from the code above is this:
[image]

Any ideas on how can I get this to work? Why is it that I tell the text to wrap and it doesn't follow?

**UPDATE**

I also tried this:

```
<RichEditBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         Height="250"
                         Name="Intro"/>
```

But the result is:

[image]

The problem that I am having is that it seems that `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` does not really do anything. The only way I am able to set a decent width is by hard-coding it, for example: `Width="600"`. But if I do this my UI will not respond correctly to resizing. I also tried `HorizontalContentAlingment="Stretch"` but the result is exactly the same.

How can I get my `RichEditBox` take up all the available `Width` *and* `Wrap` at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [RichEditBox.TextWrapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.textwrapping.aspx), you'll notice that `WrapWholeWords` is invalid. You have to use

```
<RichEditBox TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
-or-
<RichEditBox TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
```

Since Wrap is the default value, you can drop the property.

```
<RichEditBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             Height="250"
             Name="Intro"/>
```

---

Edit: in reply to the updated question:

A control only takes the width of it's parent control. Some container controls (e.g. `Grid`) automatically take the full width available, while others (e.g. `StackPanel`) only take the required size of it's children. Using `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` in combination with a `StackPanel` as a parent control, will only use the `MinWidth` property instead of the full available width on your screen. Sometimes you can't directly see this issue, e.g. when your control is inside an itemtemplate of a `ListView`. Use the [Live Visual Tree](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/08/07/live-visual-tree-in-visual-studio-3/) in Visual Studio to find the parent containers and locate the issue.

So in short: make sure your RichEditBox is inside a Grid (or similar control) instead of a StackPanel.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I updated the question. It seems that the problem is that the `RichEditBox` doesn't want to `Stretch`. Please check it out if you can and let me know if you have any other ideas.

Comment: Ok, so my `RichEditBox` is inside a `ListViewItem`... You are saying then that I have to put `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` in all the parents?